# Correlation among rows in a matrix: eigenvalues tell us anything about it?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a square matrix in which each rows sums to <1 and all elements are 0<=a(i,j)<=1.
I am interested in measure the correlation between elements of any pair of given rows. Would the eigenvalues of this matrix tell me any information about this correlation? For example, is the variance of eigenvalues associated with the correlation between rows (the higher the correlation, the lower is the eigenvalue variance)?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by correlation between vectors? Variance of eigenvalues?

Comment: eigenvalues are not enough, you have to analyze eigenvectors too. Is your matrix symmetric?

Comment: My matrix is not symmetric. Correlation here is the linear correlation (Pearson's) between the values of the elements of each pair of row vectors.I was wondering if the variance of eigenvalues provide information on that, since I would expect repeated eigenvalues and therefore low variance in the eigenvalues.